# Telthon and Pika in the same script

Tags: python-3.x, telethon, pika

I am finding the best way to make the telethon library work and
pika in the same script.
This is what I would like to do:
A message arrives from telethon and is sent to a rabbit queue.
At the same time the script is listening on another rabbit queue and when the message arrives this must be sent to Telegram via the telethon library.

What do you think is the best way to do all this?
Threading, Asyncio Multiprocess?
Thanks

Comment: You can use `asyncio` as both Telethon and Pika support `asyncio`.